# Weebly page frequently fails to load 3rd party scripts. What in my code is causing this race condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, widget

Sometimes on my website, I will load a page and some widgets will fail to load. If I refresh the page, they may or may not load again so I know that the widgets are not broken but there is obviously some sort of problem with how my pages load. Everything used to load fine and have recently noticed this problem across the entire site. Is there any kind of solution to fix this?

Here is the page source to an example page that frequently does not load properly:
[http://www.infoblizzard.com/tech.html](http://view-source:http://www.infoblizzard.com/tech.html)

Weebly does not allow much if any editing to the jquery. Here are the pieces of code that I can edit. Hopefully someone can help me identify some pieces in this code that are being disruptive: 
[https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=6C9D4FF074D36401!112&ithint=file%2cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!ALCU_9yQhW4ZLxU](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=6C9D4FF074D36401!112&ithint=file%2Cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!ALCU_9yQhW4ZLxU)

Thanks some much any help!

Comment: the problem seems to be with the server-side aspx file, not in JS itself.

Comment: Is this beyond anything I can control or is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: if you control the server-side code you can fix it, otherwise, you can use the widget when the server is broken.